# Tap on several clicable items at the same time fires all of it

Tags: java, android

I have a trouble with clickable elements, for example I can click two items in `ListView` at the same time with two fingers.

code for listview smth like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //open some Activity here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So with two fingers `Activty` opens twice.
The same behaviour if I click to several buttons.
The same if click on button and some tab, and so on...
It is some global solution without using `boolean` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set an [`OnItemClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) via [`setOnItemClickListener(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) in order to get the correct clicking behavior.

Comment: For ListView perhaps it is the best solution. However if tap ListView item and other tab (if app has tabs with lists in each) in tabHost, fires both actions.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of handle this is:

```
long clickedTime;
@Override
public void onItemClick(View v) {
      //open some Activity here
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - clickedTime > 100) {
             clickedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
             // ... your stufff
      }
}
```

but you should be using [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Answer (score 1):

since you look to a global solution, you can add :

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

to the properties of your activity in the manifest file,
it allow the activity to be launched only one time.
I'm talking about the activity that you aim to open in onClick of course